# PHPUnit "no test executed" when I make a coverage report, in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I triying to make a report of a coverage of my tests and I cant because when I execute the follow command:
phpunit --coverage-html C:\Users\user\report.html
I get the follow error:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\xampp\htdocs\dynamic_form\phpunit.xml


Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.00Mb

No tests executed!

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done
```

I using the phpunit.xml that comes by default in Laravel.

What can be the problem?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I add the forceCoversAnnotation="false" attribute and the problem persits.

Comment: Do you have any tests? Does the tests run properly without the coverage?

Comment: If the tests aren't running at all, you may also need a composer dump before phpunit is aware of any new tests.

Comment: @ChinLeung yes, I got tests and that run properly.

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper I run composer dump-autoload command and the problem persists

Comment: You are running an extremely old version of phpunit. In fact, it's so old that it doesn't even show on the official release history page of phpunit anymore: https://phpunit.de/supported-versions.html I would recommend updating to a new version.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel unit tests are located inside `tests` folder and they have some rules in naming in order to run them.

I had the same issue in the past and this is how i solved it:

1) Namespace must be Test\Unit (or if you have a middle folder include that but always inside Tests)

2) the name of the function you build must start with the word **test** like

```
public function testMyFunction()
{
    // Put your code here
}
```

Comment: I check that, the tests are running properly without the coverage report

Comment: the point in number 2 have to be highlighted. Today I follow tutorial on youtube, the  older version of laravel and the function without 'test' prefix is do just fine, but in newer laravel (my case laravel 8) the function name must be prefixed with 'test' word, otherwise it won't work.